# Will the types of Pokemon attracted to a lure module always be the types displayed as "nearby"?

Tags: pokemon-go

If you press on the bottom right of your screen you can see what Pokemon are nearby. I'm wondering if a lure module will exclusively attract those Pokemon or if any type can randomly appear at a Pokestop with a lure module?

Answer (score 4):

The lure module will spawn new Pokemon around it and not attract the Pokemon in the area. The same goes for [incense](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Incense).

Answer (score 2):

Bluerex is correct, but adding on to that, each area has a list of Pokemon that spawn there. So if you use a lure or essence in that area it will spawn the same types of Pokemon.

Comment: Has this been confirmed in any way aside from multitudes of users' experiences?

Comment: I have no official sources. Though that's not to say they don't exist.